# Can't change python interpreter from VS CODE Status Bar

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[Status Bar Image when python file is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43c2q.png)

pls help if you can, idk why the current active interpreter is not visible in the status bar anymore when ive python file opened, its a pain to open command pallete and then type python interpreter just to check what venv im in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feb 2022 VS Code changes:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-february-2022-release/

> Move pinned interpreter status bar item towards the right behind `pythonInterpreterInfoPinned` experiment. ([#18282](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18283))

- Use language status API to move interpreter info inside the "Python" item in the right side.
- It is unpinned by default.

[image]

After pinning and hovering:

[image]

**UPDATE 17/03/2022**:
Looks like on latest VS Code update they have removed {}, and the interpreter is now permanently pinned to the right of "python"
[image]

Comment: Have been looking for hours to figure out why one machine is showing interpreter and other does not.... This worked fine, thanks guys,.

Comment: Huh! I did not notice that clicking on "Python" is now different from clicking on "{}". The latter lets you change the interpreter. Confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can just tap **CTRL + Shift + P** and typing *Python Interpreter*, it'll will show in VS Code a way to you select a interpreter.